# How to get pivot item index, knowing its name

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

How to get in VBA pivot item index knowing pivot item's name?

I would like to get the reverse of this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("MyFiledName").PivotItems(10).Name
```

Knowing that the item name is "Something", I want to get the index:

```
.PivotItem(THISNUMBER).Name
```

**Update.** 
Following the answer of Marco Getrost I end up with error. It can be reproduced using the [example file](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B3TGVycQLkZ_UUZCM3RmQUx5czg&export=download). I keep getting "Error 2042". The only case I do not get an error is when I select the item on the PageFilter as the only item (no Multiple Selection enabled) - in that case I always get position number 1.

In the example file I want to get the position number of item with Name="6" which obviously is 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim pvItem As PivotItem
Dim c as Long

For Each pvItem in ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("MyFiledName").PivotItems

c = c+1
If pvItem.Name = "Something" Then Exit For

Next pvItem

'THISNUMBER = c

End Sub
```

EDIT: After checking the official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivotitem_properties.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (which is really helpful), the answer is yes, and this is how:

```
THISNUMBER = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("MyFiledName").PivotItems("Something").Position
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it without loop?

Comment: Check my Edit... I didn't check the documentation before i wrote that.

Comment: I always get 1. No matter which item i select.

Comment: What do you mean by select? You need to change "Something" to whatever you need, then it should give you the index of that pivot item.

Comment: Today I keep getting "Error 2042"

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question, or post here what code your are currently trying?